# How to properly hash a pair of pointers?

Tags: c++, pointers, hash, unordered-map, std-pair

I have a `std::unordered_map` with keys of type `std::pair<T*, T*>` (i.e., a pair of pointers).

The code base has the following hash functor defined:

```
struct pair_hash {
  template<typename T>
  std::size_t operator()(std::pair<T, T> const &p) {
    return (std::hash<T>()(p.first) + 0x9e3779b9) ^ (std::hash<T>()(p.second) + 0x9e3779b9);
  }
};
```

And is used as:

```
std::unordered_map<std::pair<T*, T*>, U, pair_hash> myDictionary;
```

where `U` is an arbitrary object.

Now the hash functor displayed above must have certain issues because in VC++ it gives me an out of bounds crash in `std::unordered_map::find`.

### Q:

- Could it be that my hash functor is problematic or this behaviour is attributed to VC++ itself?
- Is there a "proper/more proper" way to hash a pair of pointers?

Comment: Why not use [`std::hash`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash)?

Comment: @NathanOliver: There is no `std::hash` for `std::pair`, which is the problem. `std::hash` for pointer exists and he uses it to implement the hash function for pair.

Comment: @michalsrb Doh.  I forgot you have to make your own for `std::pair`.

Comment: Down-voter care to comment on your down-vote. And how this question is off-topic?

Answer (score 2):

```
return (std::hash<T>()(p.first) + 0x9e3779b9) ^ (std::hash<T>()(p.first) + 0x9e3779b9);
//                                                                ^^^^^
//                                                              p.second!
//                                                                         ^^^^^^^^^^
// Choose different magic constant to prevent collisions between (p1, p2) and (p2, p1)
```

Your function was returning zero for every pair of pointers. Therefore you were getting lots of collisions in the `unordered_map`.

Comment: Nice to know, but is there a better hashing for a pair of pointers? Plus I corrected the `p.second` part.

Comment: @101010, how is your combiner bad? What test have you performed to know it doesn't fit your needs?

Comment: @StoryTeller I didn't run any. VC++ crashes at `std::unordered_map::find` because of this hasher. Perhaps you could en-light me and suggest some.

Comment: @101010, even after the fix?

Comment: @StoryTeller No there's no fix, that was accidentally written by me in the question. The original code is the one with the correction.

Answer (score 2):

If you can use Boost, there's a very useful [`hash_combine`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/hash/combine.html) function that you could use.

Comment: And even if you can't, it's simple enough to roll out your own by boosts example